# laravel-5.8 validation required field if a certain radio button is checked

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I have this tow `radio` buttons and they are `required`

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('wc', trans('interface.notificationForWebMobile'), ['class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <label><input type="radio" name="web" value="web"> {{trans('interface.Website')}}</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="web" value="clients"> {{trans('interface.mobApp')}}</label>
 </div>
```

and I have this two fields.

```
{!! Form::text('route', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>trans('interface.notificationRoute')]) !!}

{!! Form::select('clients_view', [
                            null => 'Please select',
                            'Home' => 'Home',
                            'Search'=>'Search',
                            'Registration'=>'Registration',
                            'Login'=>'Login',], ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>trans('interface.notificationRoute')]) !!}
```

I need to validate this two fields as required depending on checked radio button

- as if radio button value is `web` then the `route` field is required
- and if the radio value is `clients` then the `clients_view` menu is required.

here is my current `Request`

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            'title'   => 'required',
            'details' => 'required',
            'web'     => 'required',
            'route'     => 'required_with:',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault try to use `required_with` it should be `required_if`

here is my final request if someone is interested

```
return [
            'title'        => 'required',
            'details'      => 'required',
            'web'          => 'required',
            'route'        => 'required_if:web,web',
            'clients_view' => 'required_if:web,clients',
        ];
```